# Base de datos para un proyecto de amalarmas

Tags: base-de-datos, flutter

Estoy realizando un diagrama de una base de datos para un proyecto de un app de alarmas comunitarias, e echo este diagrama pero no lo se si esta bien estruturado.

- El usuario puede crear varios grupos "familiar, comunitario, etc."
- El usuario puede ingresar a ese grupo varias personas y una persona puede pertenecer a varios grupos para ello cree un tabla gropu_users que se encargar de agregar el id del usuario y del grupo para hacer las realciones entre los dos.
- en la tabla Alrmas se registra el usuario que la alnzo y el motivo con un estado. [image: Para este proyecto la base de datos esta bien estructurada? me podrian ayudar a revisar su funcionalidad]

Comment: Mas alla que para diseñar una DB se necesitan todas las reglas de negocios y en algunos casos, se puede basar en opiniones, en este caso me pongo en profesor y te pregunto, para que guardas id_group y id_user en la tabla alarma, si tenes justamente una tabla que relaciona esas dos cosas!!!!!!! y ademas, supongamos que un usuario se vaya de un grupo... eso como se cambia??? donde hay un campo inactivo o borrado o lo que sea????

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @gbianchi, este es un proyecto personal para una app de flutter y en realidad no tengo experiensia realizando la base de datos, las reglas son simples, un usuario puede crear tantos grupos como quiera, y dentro de ellos agregar a otros usuarios es por llo que creo una nueva tabal group_users para hacer la relacion entre los usuarios y los grupos, un usario puede estar en varios grupos, el campo de estado del usuario no lo tome en cuenta, gracias por ese dato : ).

Comment: En la tabla User, pueda que falten campos básicos: fecha de alta del usuario, fecha modificado; posiblemente la aplicación use roles de usuarios, así que necesitará un campo de privilegio (admin, operador, solo ver, deshabilitado).